# Removing badges from profile.

Tags: support, feature-request, reputation, badges

Is it possible to remove badges if you do not want them? If not, is that something you would consider adding as a feature?

Answer (score 7):

No, this is not possible. I doubt it will be implemented.

If you find it distracting you can hide them locally (others will still see them). For details see: 
[How to disable/remove all badges and reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40777/how-to-disable-remove-all-badges-and-reputation) and https://stackapps.com/questions/3105/hide-all-pointless-user-data-gravatar-badges-and-reputation

Comment: Thank you, but as far as I understand that only removes what I see myself? I would like to remove what is visible on my profile to everyone, no just myself.

Comment: Yes, this is only for yourself.  As I said, removing it for everybody is not possible.